# User information in a model post_save email

Tags: django

I have a model into I send an email each time this model is edited, with post_save, nice!

I can recover fields from my model to display them in the email, good.

But I would display information about the user connected, logged (username...).
I tried some syntaxes, without success, please can you help me?

In model.py, at the end of my model related:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save(self, **kwargs):
    text = 'Hello\n%s %s has just been edited.' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
    my_from = 'webmaster@hg-map.fr'
    my_subject = 'Prospect Edit (from test instance, home)'

    email = EmailMessage(my_subject, text, my_from, to=['xxx@xxx.fr'])
    email.send()
```

Comment: oops...this is something weird. Seems like you have connected the *instance method* to signal. Is your `post_save` signal working?

Comment: Hello, yes it works as it. Why? You see some weird coding? Please tell me

Comment: Mmmm... finally you right. It works good until... I restart the server...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now I do it, at the bottom of models.py:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModelRelated)
def save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    text1 = 'Hello\n%s %s has just been edited.' % (instance.first_name, instance.last_name)
    form_admin_url = 'Admin form: https://xxx.fr/admin/prospect/prospect/'+str(instance.id)+'/change/'
    footer = 'This message was sent automatically, do not answer.'
    my_from = 'webmaster@xxx.fr'
    my_subject = 'Prospect Edited (%s %s)' % (instance.first_name, instance.last_name)

    email = EmailMessage(my_subject, text1+'\n'+form_admin_url+'\n'+footer, my_from, to=['geo@xxx.fr'])
    email.send()
```